# Template Builder in Mac

Tags: template-builder

As far as I can read on http://sdl.ssl.cdn.sdlmedia.com/file/635080284284402465YT.pdf (page 135), "Template Builder runs on any Microsoft Windows release supported for the
Content Manager Explorer client".

Is there any way to install it on Macintosh?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. As mentioned on the [Template Builder prerequisites](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9F8E1929-3F3B-41A5-AF14-7837B869286B) page of the online docs, only Windows client machines are supported. This is probably because the full .Net Framework (v4.6.2 or v4.5.2 for SDL Tridion Sites 8.5) needs to be available on the client machine and also because Internet Explorer is needed for the ClickOnce installer (although there are ways around this).

Of course, you could use a Windows VM on your Mac.

Comment: I hear nice things about Parallels (https://www.parallels.com/eu/), not sure if it also works for the Template Builder

Comment: @Hechss - No problem. Please feel free to accept the answer if you're happy that it's correct :)